# How to monitor user activity on docker

Tags: docker

Linux provides psacct or acct tools in order to monitor user activity. I tried to run acct on docker but it always returns an empty response. Is there a way I can track user activity on docker?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't make sense to monitor user activity in docker, as docker container is not a virtual machine. You container should give a service, not sshd daemon.
You should monitor container activities. You can do it running some of the following commands on your docker server, based on docker built-in API: docker ps   docker stats  docker topor using cAdvisor or other tools.

Comment: @gile I agree, it should give a service, but what about unexpected activities of this service or malware inside? Is there a way to list an access to docker resources?

Comment: I would check application or system logs, e.g. "docker exec -ti -u root yourContainer tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log" or "docker exec -ti -u root yourContainer grep someString /var/log/apache2/access.log"

Comment: `docker logs` is shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

`docker top`

(see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/top/

and notice it allows the ps options, an example

`docker top my_container -e -o pid,cmd`

will show the pid and command of all processes inside the container

and

`docker stats`

see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/

If you want to go durther, you have docker-py in order to get more information about the performance inside the docker container

https://github.com/docker/docker-py

Comment: Thanks, it's useful but provides only partial functionality,  is there a way to have somthing similar to lastcomm?

Comment: see some solutions on https://blog.couchbase.com/2016/april/monitoring-docker-containers-docker-stats-cadvisor-universal-control-plane cadvisor being my preferred